# How do I create a simple mean and standard deviation in gtsummary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to use gtsummary in R to create an overall mean and standard deviation for 2 variables that measure pain: pain_p0, pain_p3. Each of these variables has 10 levels that have been converted to the numerical class.

The code I am using produces summary statistics for each variable and for each of their 10 levels. For example, there are 5 people who reported a pain level of "2", and there are 8 people who reported a level of "4" but I cannot create output that displays an overall mean of all values from all people (2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)/13 = mean of 3.23 and stdev = 1.01

```
table3 <- select(df_pcn, pain_p0, pain_p3) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean}"
  )
table3
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You could do with `statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± {sd}"`.

Comment: In addition to @YHJang 's suggestion,  you may need to add `type = c(df_pcn, pain_p0, pain_p3) ~ "continuous"` to force a continuous summary. Variables with few unique values may default to a categorical summary.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. That did the trick. For others, remember that is df_pcn is a dataframe, then drop the first term of the type command......type = c(pain_p0, pain_p3) ~ "continuous"

Comment: Yes, thanks @DanielD.Sjoberg.
And remember, if df_pcn is the dataframe in the original code, then drop it in the type command.